# Qemu disk virtio performance on Windows 10 guest

Tags: windows, qemu, virtio

Is this speed normal?

**Host**: 64-bit archlinux

**Guest**: WIndows 10 64-bit Education Edition with redhat virtio stable driver, raw disk format, 32GB size, virtio enabled, kvm enabled.

start command:

```
 qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=/backup/qemu/f1-node,if=virtio,format=raw -m 2G -enable-kvm -vga std -display vnc=:2,password=on -monitor stdio
```

I feel the `Apache`/`PostgreSQL` inside really sluggish (took about 2 seconds to respond each request)

[image: sluggish]

[image: task manager performance]

[image: task manager processess]

**UPDATE**

after moving to SSD and increase to 4GB of RAM:

[image: faster sequential, slower random]
[image: random response time, 2x write speed]
[image: task manager ssd]

Where is the bottleneck and how to improve the performance?

Comment: 1. what kind of disk performance do you get on the host?  2. if you've set up LVM on your linux box, try giving the VM an LVM LV rather than a disk image file (at least it's raw which has better performance than qcow2).  3. what other VMs are running that might impact performance?   4. You have a Linux box, yet you're running both apache AND postgresql in a Windows VM?  that's...insane.  Even if your web site needs Windows, postgresql doesn't and will perform better on a dedicated Linux or FreeBSD VM.  It's a good idea to separate web and db servers, anyway.

Comment: 1. host was about 500MB/s | 2. ah ic | 3. there is other vm, but really low resource consumption | 4. it's our "mandatory" goverment's software, that have some protection so it can only run on windows..

Comment: what does "ah ic" mean?  Anyway, what's the disk performance in other (windows & linux) VMs like?  and maybe try a fresh install of win10 in a VM and see if that performs badly too.  Install pg on it and load it up with some junk data for testing.  if that's ok, install apache too and test it with both static pages and then with pg query pages.    Re: "4" - does the protection stop you from moving the pg database to another machine/VM?  If it's hard-coded to use 127.0.0.1:5432 can you proxy or ssh tunnel it to othervm:5432?

Comment: btw, is that the actual qemu command line you ran or did you trim it for posting?  A typical qemu command line is around 2KB long.  yours is under 150 characters.  Are you running qemu yourself from the command line or using something like libvirt and virsh/virt-manager?  at the very least, you should use `-machine=...,accel=kvm,...` as well as `-enable-kvm`.  and maybe try `-cpu=host` or `-cpu=qemu64`.

Comment: ah ic = ah i see

Comment: i'm running from command line using example from archlinux's wiki

Comment: this is fresh installation of windows 10

Comment: I have the same problem 64bit Windows 10 under KVM on 64bit Linux. 32bit Windows 10 runs much faster.